# XEN using eth1 for its bridgeing

Tags: xen

I had a XEN VM machine running correctly until I brought eth1 up in the dom0 to use for Heartbeat...

Since I activated eth1 XEN does not bridge on eth0 anymore but selects eth1?

How can I tell XEN to use eth0 as its' default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/etc/xen/xend-config.sxp` file  has an entry for managing the network script.  Look for something like this:

```
(network-script 'network-bridge netdev=eth1')
```

And change it to use eth0.